# MongoDB create 2dsphere indexes with array of features for spatial query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to create a 2dsphere index on the "features" field in MongoDB. But it contains an array of GeoJSON LineStrings. Without this array, I could create 2dsphere index only for a single GeoJSON LineString like `db.collection.createIndex({ loc : "2dsphere" )`. I want to perform a spatial query like `collection.find({ $features: { $geometry: bounding_box } })`

Does anyone know how to create a 2dsphere for the array of GeoJSON objects?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "name" : "street_segment_names",
    "features" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "Feature",
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "LineString",
                "coordinates" : [ 
                    [.,.],[.,.],[.,.]
                ]
            },
            "properties" : {
                "speed_limit" : 20
            }
        }, 
        {
            "type" : "Feature",
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "LineString",
                "coordinates" : [ 
                    [.,.],[.,.],[.,.]
                ]
            },
            "properties" : {
                "speed_limit" : 30
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB does not support "Feature" as a GeoJSON object type.  See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/#geojson-objects

The structure shown in the question includes a "geometry" field in the features object that appears to be a supported object type.

You could create an index on that field using:

```
db.collection.createIndex({"features.geometry":"2dsphere"})
```

Depending on your goal with the "bounding box" query, you might use [$geoWithin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/#geowithin) or [$geoIntersects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects/#geointersects), like

```
db.collection.find({
  "features.geometry":{
     $geoWithin: {
        $geometry: {
           type: <"Polygon" or "MultiPolygon"> ,
           coordinates: [ <coordinates> ]
        }
     }
  }
})
```

Comment: That helps. Thank you!